# Fast Bulk from C# to Oracle

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, bulk

I am developing a program to writing data to an oracle table. my data is about 1 billion rows. i use OracleBulkCopy class to bulk dataReader to oracle Table. my bulk speed is ~2.3 million rows per minute.

i do same work for sqlServer about ~7 million record per minute in same condition (hardware, software(windows server 2012)).

how can i have fast bulk for oracle, ~2.3 million rows is not suitable for my work.
my oracle bulk code is as below:

```
private static void BulkToORacle(DataTable dt)
        {
            var connectionString = GetORacleConnectionString();
            using (var oracleConnecion = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
            {
                oracleConnecion.Open();
                using (var bulk = new OracleBulkCopy(oracleConnecion, OracleBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction))
                {
                    bulk.DestinationTableName = "T1";
                    bulk.BatchSize = 50000;
                    bulk.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
                    bulk.WriteToServer(dt.CreateDataReader());
                }
            }
        }
```

thanks.

Comment: Did you experiment with different BatchSize ?

Comment: yes. my first expriment the batch size was= 10000, and i change it to 50000, and that was good. 50000 was better than 10000

Comment: in sqlserver i changed the AutoGrowth  size to 1024 MB,  and log of db from full to simple. then the rate became better

Comment: I suspect you'll get much better Oracle bulk insert performance with the `SQL*LOADER` utility, although it would be a bit of a kludge to invoke that programmatically.

Comment: SQL *LOADER has some limitation for me. i should have a space on destination to make a file. so making a file is not a good solution,